# Code compiles and links but does not run (at all, loading libraries fails)

Tags: c++

Yesterday I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253515/no-idea-as-to-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxxabi-1-3-8 and I've found no-one who has even seen the error before (I'd love not to loose rep to leave that out there for others to find....) and I've managed to reproduce the error

```
template<class T>
class Matrix {
protected:
    T* data;
    int m,n;
public:
    Matrix(int M, int N): m(M), n(N) {
        data = new T[m*n];
    }
    ~Matrix() { delete[] data; }
};

class Object {
public:
    Object() {}
    ~Object(){}
};

int main(void) {
    Matrix<double> test(2,2);
    return 0;
}
```

However change `Matrix<double>` to `Matrix<Object>` and it's fine.

I honestly have no idea why, and this is the first time I've ever had such an error, I'm not sure what I'm doing differently compared to every other time I've done something similar.

**Addendum**

I doubted myself so much I tried "double* test = new double[10];" and stuff, and deleting it, it worked (shocking! not)

Comment: You need to include information about what compiler you're using, what command line you gave it, and if there are any other compilers on the system. Look for multiple versions of libstdc++ in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: @SoapBox GCC 4.9 (compiled yesterday) bog standard -Wall -Wextra, I do not have conflicting libraries, GCC passed the testsuit.

Comment: @SoapBox additionally other stuff works, by other stuff I mean iostream, vector lists.... wxWidgets... stuff I've used for years, I've changed nothing but for some reason it HATES this. I have no idea why.

Comment: It sounds to me like you can a comflict with the other version of GCC (the one you used to compile this version).  The easiest way to test that is to completely remove the extra versions of GCC so you have exactly ONE installed.  If that works then you need to spend some time sorting our your GCC compile and install and your environment variables.  Having 2 versios of GCC installed can be difficult tog et to work correctly.

Comment: @SoapBox I don't have two versions, I've checked all this stuff. I'm here because I am out of ideas

Comment: @SoapBox I know it looks like "noob can't get compiler to work" but I've been playing with GCC for a while now, initially I thought I broke something so I compiled fresh from trunk. The work being done on removing the tree macros is very interesting I've been rebuilding a lot because of that alone.

Comment: So you compiled it and installed over top of the version you used to compile it?

Comment: @SoapBox no, GCC builds in three stages, stage 1 uses the old compiler to build the stage 2, then stage 2 builds stage 2 and calls that stage 3. Stage 3 then builds the compiler again and that is compared with the result of stage 2. So the compiler I have was literally compiled by itself.

Comment: I know that, but something had to build stage 1.  Where is that compiler now?  Did you uninstall it, or install the new version over top, or leave it there?

Comment: That compiler is gone, like the one before it, and the one before that.... @SoapBox on a good patch day I rebuild like twice, I've done this a lot and before.

Comment: You still didn't really answer.  If you uninstalled all old compilers before installing this one then I have no suggestions for you.  BUt it ounds like you're just installing the new one overtop the old one, which can leave pieces laying around.  Or you forgot that your distro comes with 4.1 or something and its still on there.  Build GCC out of place, remove all old compilers and verify they are gone.  Then install GCC into the normal path or alter your environment to point to it.

Comment: @SoapBox as always. I'm not a noob. This gets weirder btw, if I replace n*m with "10" or something it works. but using m*n or M*N does not with double.

Comment: I've had this exact same problem and its always been my PATH pointing to the distro default GCC instead of the one I just built.

Comment: @SoapBox alec@ATLaptop ~/workspace $ which g++
/usr/local/bin/g++
alec@ATLaptop ~/workspace $ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.9.0 20131127 (experimental)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Are you sure that the change you're making aren't just impacting what get optimized away?  It could be that replacing one of those values with constants causes the whole program to become trivial, hiding the problem.

Comment: @SoapBox I know, I just thought it was interesting. I really have no idea what could not be working.

Comment: Remove (or move away) the libstdc++ listed in the error message and run the install part of the gcc build again, see if that library comes back or not.  MD5 it with the one in the build directory of GCC to make sure  its really the same.  Try manually copying.  And for good measure do a find on / for any other libstdc++

Comment: @SoapBox I've done that already, I am CERTAIN there are no others, I'll approach the mailing list instead.

Comment: @SoapBox thanks for trying btw. I appreciate that. My last attempt was quickly closed - it was nice to get human messages on the matter.